# How to remove extra space after delimiter which caused due to entering each data in a new line after delimiter in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have comma separated data in DB where each comma separated data is in new line like below

Computer Accessories,

Laptop Dealers,

CCTV Dealers,

computer sales,

computer service center

When i execute a query with LIKE "%,computer sales,%", its not returning any value. how to remove the extra spaces or is there any query which will consider the space and return value

Comment: `I have comma separated data` If I had a nickel...

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
where COL rlike '[:space:]*computer sales,[:space:]*'
```

Comment: It is working fine but is it correct if i write it as rlike '[:space:]*".$category.",[:space:]*' in php prepared statement

Comment: It should work as per my understanding. Please give it a try!

Comment: It worked for every data apart from the last one as there is no comma

Comment: did u mention the condition for the last one as: COL rlike '[:space:]*computer service center[:space:]*' .. ? (without comma)